# Css file loads from s3 bucket but not domain

Tags: css, amazon-s3, amazon-route53

I am having a weird issue which I cannot find a solution for. Css works perfectly when loading from my s3 bucket:
[Direct s3 access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOVR5.png).
But when I attempt to load from my domain the css does not load: [Domain access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxUOb.png).
It does show up in the sources, however: [sources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JikAi.png).
Sometimes (not always) I get the warning: "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/plain:".

I've already configured the metadata for the css file to be "text/css". What else could I be missing?

Comment: This is likely a cache problem. A trick is to change the name in the HTML-code of the css file into style?new.css for example. In that case the DOM thinks it's a new file and will reload it for you. When it happens again just change the name after ?.

Comment: That seems to have fixed the problem. I changed the name of the file and now it is working. Thanks!